# Javascript: make an object inherit array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

```
var RPNCalculator = function() {
    this.stack = [];
    this.total = 0;
    this.value = function() {
        return this.total;
    }
    this.push = function(val) {
       this.stack.push(val);
    }
    this.pop = function() {
        this.stack.pop();
    }
    this.process = function() {
        this.val1 = this.stack.pop();
        this.val2 = this.stack.pop();
        this.total = 0;
    }
    this.plus = function() {
        this.process();
        this.total = this.val1 + this.val2;
        this.stack.push(this.total);  
    }
    this.minus = function() {
        this.process();
        this.total = this.val2 - this.val1;
        this.stack.push(this.total);  
    }
}
```

How can I make the RPNCalculator object inherit array methods, without creating push and pop methods myself?
For example, if I do the following

```
rpnCalculator = new RPNCalculator();
rpnCalculator.push(2);
```

it will add the number 2 to the stack array

Comment: Your best bet would be not to use a `.stack` property and instead make `RPNCalculator` instance array-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all of the methods provided by `Array` maybe start with inheriting the prototype from `Array` using [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and then adding your custom functions to the new constructor prototype.

```js
var Foo = function () {};
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
Foo.prototype.process = function process() {
  // `this` is the array
  // Do some logic...

  // returning `this` to show it is the array
  return this;
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.push(3);
foo.push(2);
foo.push(1);

document.write(
  '<h3>foo</h3>' + 
  '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(foo, null, 4) + '</pre>' +
  '<h3>foo.process()</h3>' +
  '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(foo.process(), null, 4) + '</pre>'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will do my best to learn from these.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

`this.push = this.stack.push.bind(this.stack);
 this.pop = this.stack.pop.bind(this.stack);`

That would just use `stack`'s methods instead of defining your own.

Comment: thank you. i was under the impression that there was a way to define the object using prototypes, so that it could inherit all the array methods. something involving underscoreunderscorePROTOunderscoreunderscore. i am very new to this so i apologize if i am not making much sense.

Comment: Check out Jason's answer

Comment: The problem you defined does not need prototypical inheritance to solve it though. Since you only need two methods, why bring in everything else Array.protype has?

Comment: You are correct, I do not need to inherit all the Array properties. Your answer was very helpful, and it's a technique I was not aware of. I just figured while I am here I could get more information relevant to the topic.